# Asp button validation and submission in a single function..post backs

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I use visual studio 2013 and web forms. I have a javascript function to pass text box value to change the title. I have a condition that alerts to pass real value when no value is passed. and when a value is passed that value will be substituted in the place of title. The problem in my code is when i pass no value and click button it is not showing any alert. Although it substituting to the place of title when i pass the value. Please help me with this.

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function substitute() {
         var isValid = true;
         var myValue = document.getElementById('<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>').value;
        if (myValue.length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter a real value');
            return;
        }
        var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
        myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
      return false;
   }

</script>
```

This is my Html:

```
<h1 id="title">Javascript Example</h1>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" id="myTextBox" />
<asp:Button runat="server"  Text="click me" OnClientClick="return substitute();" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your code I do see the alert popup which says 'Please enter a real value', if I enter nothing in the text box and click the button. Here is the complete code for my aspx. Please verify that it is the same as yours, except for the namespace and page name on line 1:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="test.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyNamespace.test" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>,
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function substitute() {
            var isValid = true;
            var myValue = document.getElementById('<%= myTextBox.ClientID %>').value;
               if (myValue.length == 0) {
                   alert('Please enter a real value');
                   return;
               }
               var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
               myTitle.innerHTML = myValue;
               return false;
           }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <h1 id="title">Javascript Example</h1>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" ID="myTextBox" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="click me" OnClientClick="return substitute();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem was type=text in asp:textbox .. It worked for me when i removed it. Anyway thanks a lot :)